# How to pass a list from one function to another function in Python3 across three files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been banging my head for some time regarding this and I know it might end up being something stupid but my import game is non-existent.

Basically, I have four files on the same directory: `fs.py`, `z.py`, `match.py`, `y.py`.

The function from `fs.py` and function from `z.py` feeds into `match.py`. From there, the results of `match.py` feeds into `y.py` (This is where I get an issue).

When I feed the list from `match.py` into `y.py`, the list is empty and doesn't have anything.

Each file has a bit of code, but the general flow of logic is below. I'm thinking it has to do with the way I'm importing in my last file: `y.py`.

I'm able to get what I want when I run `match.py` so I know the results from `fs.py` and `z.py` are being fed in properly. I've printed out the list which will goes into `y.py` from `match.py` to see if I get anything and it's not an empty list so I'm not sure why it's being passed in as an empty list to the function in `y.py`. Am I suppose to also import `fs` and `z` in `y.py`?

fs.py:

```
def get_fs():
    y_params = [1, 2, 4]
    return y_params
if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_fs()
```

z.py:

```
def get_z():
    y_params = [3, 5, 4]
    return y_params
if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_z()
```

match.py

```
from fs import get_fs
from z import get_z

def create_list(fs=[], z=[]):
    match_list = []
    match_list = fs + z
    return match_list
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fs = get_fs()
    z = get_z()
    create_list(fs, z)
```

y.py

```
from match import create_list

def create_new_list(match_list=[]):
     print(match_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    match_list = create_list()
    create_match_list(match_list)
```

If someone has any idea, I would really appreciate it. I've been trying to figure this out for the last 2 hours and I'm fairly new to python. T_T I can also add the original code as well.

Comment: you don't need `if __name__ == "__main__"`if you are using these files as modules.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have misinterpreted the concept of `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which you have used in your code. This `if` condition evaluates to `True` only if you execute `python file.py`, if you are **importing** `file.py` to some other module, it won't get executed.

Now in your case `match.py` has the list initializer placed inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"`, which would be evaluated only when you run `python match.py` If you import `match` to some other file, the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition would evaluate to false and hence your lists would be empty.

Comment: So, from what I'm understanding, when I run ./match.py, I can see the lists from fs and z because the lists are not being initialized in their own files and because match.py is being executed. However, having if __name__ == '__main__' becomes an issue when I try to initialize a list to pass in to another function since match.py is no longer executed? It looks like I just need to first initialize the list in y.py from match.py and just call the function towards the end? Please let me know if I'm totally off my line of thinking....

Comment: You seem to be a bit off here. The point is if you run `python match.py` the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block is executed, which initializes the lists, But when you `import match`, the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block isn't executed and hence `create_list(fs=[], z=[])` gets empty lists as default arguments.